# Why my curve_fit reach the maxfev = 10000?

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I am trying to do fit but I each maxfev even after increasing it to 10000!. I think I am doing something wrong.

I will be looping through 4 stacks of images of the same size (30X240X240), and get the values of the same voxel at the 4 different images. So for your reference my loop will use n=30, d=240

```
v1, v2, v3, v4 = 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000

xdata = np.array([50,300,600,1000])

D_map = np.zeros((n,d,d))
K_map = np.zeros((n,d,d))

def kurtosis(x, D, K):
    return (-x * D) + (1/6 * (x **2)* (D **2) * K)

for i in range(n):
    for r in range(d):
        for c in range(d):
            v1 = b50_data[i,r,c]
            if v1 < 28:
                D_map[i,r,c] = 0
                K_map[i,r,c] = 0
            else:
                v2 = b300_data[i,r,c]
                v3 = b600_data[i,r,c]
                v4 = b1000_data[i,r,c]
                ydata = np.array([v1,v2, v3, v4])
                ydata = np.log(ydata/v1)

                popt, pcov = curve_fit(kurtosis, xdata, ydata, maxfev= 10000)
                D_map[i,r,c] = popt[0] * 1000
                K_map[i,r,c] = popt[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have reached a solution.

I used the 
`try: except:` to pass any operation that will take so long and return an error.

my code now is

```
try:
  popt, pcov = curve_fit(kurtosis, xdata, ydata, maxfev= 5000)
except:
  popt = [0,0]

D_map[i,r,c] = popt[0] * 1000
K_map[i,r,c] = popt[0]
```